# problem in the allocation of an object in a table

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a singleton CarteManager, it is composed of an array carteMan of carte

```
 @interface CartesManager : NSObject {


NSMutableArray *carteMan ; 

       }
```

---

```
@interface Carte : NSObject {

    NSString *titre ; 
    NSString *commentaire ; 
    UIImage *image1 ; 
    UIImage *image2 ; 
    NSMutableArray *information ; 
}
```

and after i wont to allocation all image of carte in CarteMan to a array image

```
- (id)init
{
    int i ; 
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil])

    {
        NSMutableArray * images =[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];

        for (i=0; i<([[CartesManager sharedInstance].carteMan count]); i++) {

            [images addObject:[[[[CartesManager sharedInstance]carteMan]image1]indexOfObject:i]]; //don"t work
        }
        self.view = [[[SlideShowView alloc] initWithImages:images] autorelease];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: [images addObject:[[[[CartesManager sharedInstance]carteMan]image1]indexOfObject:i]]; //don"t work

Comment: What is the question? ("don't work" is extremely vague. Does it fail to compile? Does it make your computer explode when you run it? Does your application gradually run out of memory when it runs for a week? Does it display the wrong thing on the screen?)

Comment: More specifically: (1) What were you hoping your code would do? (2) What, exactly, did it do instead?

Comment: my problem is that this assignment does not work

Comment: NSMutableArray does not respond to -image1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulating so many objects and methods are the best way to drive you insane by searching bugs ;-)

Do it step by step and you'll get the right answer:

I'm sure, the solution will be something like this: (but)

```
CartesManager *cartesManager = [CartesManager sharedInstance];

[images addObject:[[cartesManager image1] objectAtIndex:i]];
```

(but) I don't really get the structure of CartesManager. Does CartesManager have an "image1"-Array with images? Or could you just post your CartesManager.h?

OK, I read your edit, but I'm still not sure what you want ;-)

May something like this?

```
CartesManager *cartesManager = [CartesManager sharedInstance];
Carte *carte = [[Carte alloc] init];
carte = [cartesManager carteMan] objectAtIndex:i]

[images addObject:[carte image1]];
[images addObject:[carte image2]];
```

Comment: @interface CartesManager : NSObject {
 
 
 NSMutableArray *carteMan ; 
 NSInteger indexCarteCourante ;
 NSInteger numImage ; 
 BOOL isEditable ;

}

Comment: in a card images already there and i want to go the whole picture card "Carteman" has to see pictures of each card "image1" to "carte"

Answer (score 0):

You're effectively calling, somewhere inside that nest of calls,

```
[carteMan image1]
```

where `carteMan` is an `NSMutableArray`. That's not going to work! I think you want to interchange the order of `image1` and `objectAtIndex:i`. (You actually wrote `indexOfObject`, but I don't think you meant it.) Thus:

```
[images addObject:[[[[CartesManager sharedInstance] carteMan] objectAtIndex:i] image1]];
```